# Explanation for the code needed

Tags: c++

Someone wrote the following code when asked to **Input N integers seperated by a whitespace**

```
  do
   {
       cin>>temp;
      name[i]=temp;


       if(i==N-1)
           break;
       i++;


   }while(true);
```

Here it is initialized to zero. I want to know why this piece of code works correctly. If I give the following input with `N=4` ,
`2 34 5 87` , the array `name` stores the values properly. `name[0]=2 name[1]=34` and so on. 
 If I write `cout<<"Hello"` after the cin statement, it doesn't execute until I press return. Basically I want to know how the loop is actually working. Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: What makes you think it is correct code? Given that it isn't checked whether input was successful, it is clearly wrong. Also, it doesn't work for `N == 0` as it reads at least one element. BTW, what is your specific question?

Comment: Well, I used it in a CodeChef problem and it worked correctly. :)

Comment: What is the code supposed to do?

Comment: @AkshayArora: so it isn't that you don't know what this program does but you also fail to test boundary conditions?

Comment: I am a beginner, Just trying a lot of things. @JohnPeyton, the code is supposed to take N integers seperated by a space and store them in an array. Any better way to do that?

Comment: @AkshayArora Yes there are several ways, search this on SO, you'll find many answers

Comment: A correct implementation would be this: `for (int i(0); i != N && std::cin >> name[i]; ++i) {}` assuming it is made sure that `name` contains, at least, `N` elements.

Answer (score 1):

This is a `do`-`while` loop, which means it is entered at least once. Therefore the code does not correctly handle the case when `N`==`0`.

Assuming `N`>`0` and `i` is initialized to `0` and the input read from `cin` is correct, then the loop runs until the `break` statement. `break` will terminate the loop regardless of the terminating condition.

The `break` statement is executed when `i`==`N-1` is true. This occurs after `name[N-1] = temp`, which means `N` items have been assigned when the loop terminates, since `i` is incremented at each iteration for which `i`!=`N-1` is true.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `cin` treats spaces as separating your "tokens" or pieces of input. Each time `cin` is used, it will give you the number.

Now try this heavily-commented version.

```
do {
    /* Read a number */
    cin >> temp;
    /* Save the number into the i'th element of the array name */
    name[i] = temp;

    /* If we have reached the maximum size of the array as given by N, exit the loop. */
    if (i == N-1) {
        break;
    }
    /* If we haven't reached the maximum size, increase i by 1 and keep saving to the array. */
    i++;
} while(true);
```

The code isn't great. It would be better to put `(i < N-1)` as the while-condition, and not use `break` at all.

Also note that this is only a piece of a larger function. The larger function must declare the variables (such as giving a value to `N`) if it's going to work.